# Parse JSON into PL SQL with poor formatting

Tags: json, oracle

I am trying to parse JSON with poorly formatted code into sql table, however some of the values are creating problem.
Database is oracle 19.2

The json data is :

```
Insert into r_data (id,data)values
(1,'{'"View":"100",
"Assignment Title":"Collect all snippets from the Library",
"Status":"In Progress",
"Active/Not Active":"Depends"}');
```

I want the result as:

```
View  Assignment_Title                   Status       Active_Not_Active
100   Collect all snippets from Library  In progress  Depends
```

When i write the query,

```
select * from r_data x JSON_TABLE(x.data,'$',
COLUMNS (view NUMBER(10) PATH '$.view')
```

--for the first column view , it throws error of invalid identifier at the word view.
It only works fine for column Status as probably its single word and because view is keyword it is throwing problem. However i cannot change these names and want column View as View, Assignment Title as Assignment Title and Active/not Active as Active_not_Active.

How can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean by "poorly formatted code"? The JSON in your code is valid JSON (with one exception - an errant single-quote after the opening brace in the `insert` statement, but I assume that doesn't actually exist in your real code). Separately, please note that I removed the `plsql` tag; your question is about plain SQL, it has nothing to do with PL/SQL. If you think it does, please google "PL/SQL" to learn what it really means - most likely not what you thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that `view` is a reserved keyword, and therefore it can't be used as a column name (unless in double quotes - which is best avoided). You wanted to create a column named `view` from the data in your JSON - that's why you got the "invalid identifier" error.

But there are numerous other errors in your code; if you even made it as far as the "invalid identifier" error, that means that the code you posted is **not** the code you ran.

For example, even in the `insert` statement, you have an extra single-quote after the opening brace. That means that the opening brace is a string (one character) and the rest is who-knows-what. I had to remove that errant single-quote to make the `insert` work. How were you able to use that obviously syntactically incorrect statement?

In the `select` statement you are missing a comma after the alias `x` (before the keyword `JSON_TABLE`). No way you would get the "invalid identifier" error with **that** syntax error in the code.

In the JSON_TABLE function, there should be no comma between `'$'` and the `COLUMNS` clause. With that comma there, you would get a different error, not "invalid identifier" - so I don't believe that what you posted is your real code.

Etc. If all you got was an "invalid identifier" error, just choose a different name for the column (`view` won't work) and see what happens. Although... there is one more mistake, and it will result in an unexpected result. JSON is case sensitive. The attribute name in the JSON is `View`, with a capital `V`. So you must reference it as `$.View` in `JSON_TABLE`; you have `$.view`, which doesn't correspond to any attribute in your JSON, so you will get `null` for that column (if you don't change it to match capitalization from the JSON).

Here is the complete example, with all the errors corrected.

First, create the table. I do it all in one step:

```
create table r_data (id,data) as select 1,'{"View":"100",
"Assignment Title":"Collect all snippets from the Library",
"Status":"In Progress",
"Active/Not Active":"Depends"}' from dual;
```

Then, here is the query and its output. Notice the double-quotes around property names with embedded spaces (and forward slash, etc.).

```
select x.id, 
       j.view_, assignment_title, j.status, j.active_not_active 
from   r_data x,
       json_table(x.data,'$'
           columns (view_             number(10)   path '$.View',
                    assignment_title  varchar2(50) path '$."Assignment Title"',
                    status            varchar2(20) path '$.Status',
                    active_not_active varchar2(20) path '$."Active/Not Active"'
                   )
       ) j
;

ID VIEW_ ASSIGNMENT_TITLE                      STATUS      ACTIVE_NOT_ACTIVE 
-- ----- ------------------------------------- ----------- ------------------
 1   100 Collect all snippets from the Library In Progress Depends
```

Comment: For view, lets say i replace it with any other word like view_1, how will i do so for other columns as Assignment Title ,Actve/ Not Active?

Comment: @Vini - exactly the same way. List all the columns in the output table in the `COLUMNS` clause of `JSON_TABLE`, following the same format: output column name, data type, keyword `PATH`, and the path. Very similar to what you were already doing. Column definitions must be separated by comma. Note that you are also missing the closing parenthesis of the `JSON_TABLE` function (in the code you posted; probably not in the real code you ran, as that would have thrown yet another error).

Comment: @Vini  - I will edit my Reply to add the full example (with all the coding errors fixed).